# Rails group and having with two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get the last record ordered by a related model column under a certain condition.

```
# models/coin.rb
class Coin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :purchase

  # fields
  # - user_id
end

# models/purchase.rb
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :coin

  # fields
  # - expiration_date
end
```

I want to group "coin" records by "user_id" and want to get the last record of every user groups ordered by "expiration_date". What I'm trying now is as below.

```
coin_ids = Coin.joins(:purchase).where("expiration_date IS NOT NULL").group("user_id").having("expiration_date = MAX(expiration_date)").ids
coins = Coin.joins(:purchase).where(id: coin_ids)
```

It works in the environment with sqlite3, but not in the environment with mysql2 showing this error message:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'expiration_date' in 'having clause'
```

**EDIT**
I don't know why but

```
Coin.joins(:purchase).where("expiration_date IS NOT NULL").group(:user_id).having("expiration_date = MAX(expiration_date)").select('coins.*', 'purchases.expiration_date')
```

returns records, but

```
Coin.joins(:purchase).where("expiration_date IS NOT NULL").group(:user_id).having("expiration_date = MAX(expiration_date)").select('coins.*', 'purchases.expiration_date').ids
```

returns unknown column error.

If I'm missing something or more info is needed please tell me. Thanks!!

Comment: Try `purchases.expiration_date`

Comment: @chad is it working now?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I tried both purchases.expiration_date and purchase.expiration_date but it still doesn't work. Error message is same: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'purchases.expiration_date' in 'having clause'

Answer (score 0):

```
coin_ids = Coin.joins(:purchase).where("purchases.expiration_date IS NOT NULL").group("coins.user_id").having("purchases.expiration_date = MAX(purchases.expiration_date)").ids


coins = Coin.where(id: coin_ids)
```

Comment: I tried both purchases.expiration_date and purchase.expiration_date but it still doesn't work. Error message is same: 
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'purchases.expiration_date' in 'having clause'

Comment: @ChadWoo do you have `expiration_date` in `Purchase` model? to check it at rails console `Purchase.new`?

Comment: Of course there is. The query does work before it meets 'having'.
> Purchase.new
=> #<Purchase id: nil, coin_id: nil, amount: 0, method: "", account_holder: "", account_number: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, expiration_date: nil>

Comment: Or do you think there is another way to get the last record ordered by 'expiration_date' without 'having'?

Comment: I don't know why but Coin.joins(:purchase).where("expiration_date IS NOT NULL").group(:user_id).having("expiration_date = MAX(expiration_date)").select('coins.*', 'purchases.expiration_date') returns records, but with .ids it returns unknown column error.

Comment: @ChadWoo there may be many ways to do one thing can you tell me what do you exactly require?

Answer (score 0):

You should add purchases.expiration_date in the query selection. Please try:

```
coin_ids = Coin.joins(:purchase).where("expiration_date IS NOT NULL").group("user_id").having("expiration_date = MAX(expiration_date)").select('coins.*', 'purchases.expiration_date').ids
```

Comment: The query does work with sqlite3 but not with mysql2 again. Error message is still same: 
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'expiration_date' in 'having clause'

Comment: Or do you think there is another way to get the last record ordered by 'expiration_date' without 'having'?

Comment: I think using 'having' is the best solution. Can you copy the generated SQL on rails log?

Comment: I don't know why but Coin.joins(:purchase).where("expiration_date IS NOT NULL").group(:user_id).having("expiration_date = MAX(expiration_date)").select('coins.*', 'purchases.expiration_date') returns records, but with .ids it returns unknown column error.

Comment: I assumpt that `ids` is scope on your model. But if is not and you want to get  ids of returned coins. You can use `Coin.joins(:purchase).where("expiration_date IS NOT NULL").group(:user_id).having("expiration_date = MAX(expiration_date)").select('coins.*', 'purchases.expiration_date').pluck('coins.id')`